# API endpoint to show/add/modify/delete content

Tags: craft-features

I would like to access and modify certain entries using asynchronous calls from a custom made webapp using React which is complementary to the main website. Is there any way to achieve this in Craft CMS?

Answer (score 1):

I've got 0 experience with React, but you can write a Craft [plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins) (generate boilerplate code at https://pluginfactory.io), that has a [controller](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers) [action(s)](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers#posting-to-controller-actions) your webapp can post to.

From there you can use [`EntriesService->saveEntry`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/EntriesService#saveEntry-detail) (`craft()->entries->saveEntry()`) to update/create entries just like Craft/any other plugin does.